# Rounded discounted sale prices with WooCommerce bulk discount plugin

Tags: php, html, woocommerce, e-commerce, hook-woocommerce

How to create a code that round discounted sale prices on woocommerce?
This how the plugin fill $replacements

```
 public function getHtml($processedProduct)
{
    $product = $processedProduct->getProduct();

    $minDiscountRangePrice = null;
    $initialPrice          = null;
    $regularPrice          = null;
    $pos                   = null;
    if ($processedProduct instanceof ProcessedVariableProduct) {
        if ($discountRangeProcessed = $processedProduct->getLowestRangeDiscountPriceProduct()) {
            $minDiscountRangePrice = $discountRangeProcessed->getMinDiscountRangePrice();
            $initialPrice          = $discountRangeProcessed->getOriginalPrice();
            $pos                   = $discountRangeProcessed->getPos();
            $regularPrice          = $processedProduct->getLowestRangeDiscountPriceProduct()->getProduct()->get_regular_price();
        }
    } else {
        $minDiscountRangePrice = $processedProduct->getMinDiscountRangePrice();
        $initialPrice          = $processedProduct->getOriginalPrice();
        $pos                   = $processedProduct->getPos();
        $regularPrice          = $product->get_regular_price();
    }

    $replacements = array(
        'price'                 => ! is_null($minDiscountRangePrice) ? $this->priceFunctions->format($minDiscountRangePrice) : "",
        'price_suffix'          => $product->get_price_suffix(),
        'price_striked'         => ! is_null($initialPrice) ? '<del>' . $this->priceFunctions->format($initialPrice) . '</del>' : "",
        'initial_price'         => ! is_null($initialPrice) ? $this->priceFunctions->format($initialPrice) : "",
        'Nth_item'              => $pos ? $this->addSuffixOf($pos) : "",
        'regular_price_striked' => '<del>' . $this->priceFunctions->format($this->priceFunctions->getPriceToDisplay($product, array("price" => $regularPrice))) . '</del>',
    );

    return $this->formatter->applyReplacements($replacements);
}
```

Using this filter hook: $replacements = apply_filters("adp_discount_range_formatter_replacements", $replacements, $processedProduct, $this)

I have a plugin that bulk discount a percentage, but the new price have decimals: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-dynamic-pricing-for-woocommerce/

Comment: this is the function:
add_filter("adp_discount_range_formatter_replacements", function($replacements, $processedProduct, $formater){
// modify $replacements 
return $replacements;
},10,3);

Comment: and the plugin is https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-dynamic-pricing-for-woocommerce/

Comment: What I am asking since the begining: In which file of the plugin the code: `apply_filters("adp_discount_range_formatter_replacements", $replacements, $processedProduct, $this)` is located?

Comment: it's here  \BaseVersion\Includes\External\PriceFormatters\DiscountRangeFormatter.php